# Pass FTP Location to Macro Variable to Get Filenames in SAS

Tags: ftp, macros, sas

I have a SAS %get_files(location) macro to get the list of filenames in the location variable. It works for local path but how do I pass a FTP location into this location variable and get a list of filenames in there?

Here is the macro

```
%macro get_filenames(location);
filename _dir_ "%bquote(&location.)";
data filenames(keep=memname);
  handle=dopen( '_dir_' );
  if handle > 0 then do;
    count=dnum(handle);
    do i=1 to count;
      memname=dread(handle,i);
      output filenames;
    end;
  end;
  rc=dclose(handle);
run;
filename _dir_ clear;
%mend;
```

I used this FTP method but it does not work

```
filename ftpdir ftp '' ls PASSIVE
host="&sharefile_host"
user="&sharefile_ftp_user"
pass="&sharefile_ftp_pw"
recfm=v prompt;

%get_filenames("ftpdir");
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You set up the fileref inside the macro.  What happens if you pass the macro the fileref instead.  `%macro get_filenames(fileref); .. dopen ("&fileref" ); ...` Try with 1) local folder fileref, 2) the ftp fileref.  Don't pass the fileref as a quoted string.  Post the log if errors or warning occur.

Comment: How would you do it without a macro but with SAS still?